# Java selenium stale element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following element:

```
<div _ngcontent-yvb-1="" ng-reflect-class-name="d3-data-table-cell code" class="d3-data-table-cell code" ng-reflect-id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code" id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code">
    UP
  </div>
```

I made a test in Selenium using Java in which I identified the element using the `id="entity_data_manager_table_cell_code"`. The test used to pass one in 5 times but it would fail from time to time with the message `stale element`. Now the test fails all the time with message:
`stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Why is this so? The developer said that he didn't change anything. What would be the solution?

Comment: add some waits before interacting with the elements

Comment: Is that element inside any frames?

Comment: I made some research on the internet and I ran my test on several browsers. It seems the problem is related to using selenium with angular. When the same test run on another browser, e.g. Chrome there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that your element is not loaded completely till the time you access it .
Try to use explicit wait on that specific element.
Also consult with your developer to give that element a unique reference ,in case it is changing dynamically.

The stale element reference happen if a DOM operation happening on the page is temporarily causing the element to be inaccessible. To allow for those cases, you can try to access the element several times in a loop before finally throwing an exception.

And try to locate the element by classname ,

```
driver.findElement(By.className("date-header"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the exception as below

```
  public boolean retryingFindClick(By by) {
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by).click();
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

see this for more info http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/staleelementexception.html

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using this "WebElement" instead of the normal "WebElement"
the idea is from someone else I don't remember anymore.

```
public class RefreshableWebElement2 implements WebElement {

 private final WebDriver driver;
 private final By        by;

 public RefreshableWebElement2(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.by = by;
 }

 private WebElement getElement() {
   return driver.findElement(by);
 }

 @Override
 public <X> X getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) throws WebDriverException {
   return getElement().getScreenshotAs(target);
 }

 @Override
 public void click() {
   getElement().click();
 }
```

//...
}